# display a section for logged in users

Tags: php, file, text, members, visitors

Basically i've been looking for a code to put into the index page. Where let's say your new, and you see a text that says

> welcome visitor and then you login, and 
>   once you are it should say Hello .'user'.

I've looked around, but no one seems to know. One came up, although it's from wordpress, and well i put it on my code, but i believe there something missing that i don't have. I just need a simple code, please you have one let me know

> please explain the code and what I should change, cause sometimes i change things I shouldn't change and make things more complicated.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('acceso_db.php');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body,td,th {
    color: #000000;
}
a:link {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333333;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CCCCFF;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333333;
}
.style4 {
    font-family: 'EmmaSophiaRegular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', Lucida, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.style5 {
    font-family: 'EmmaSophiaRegular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', Lucida, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 44px;
}
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.style6 {font-size: 33px}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
//-->
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body onLoad="MM_preloadImages('potatos/3.jpg','potatos/wbr.png')">
<?php include_once("header_top.php"); ?>
<div id="pageMiddle" style="height:auto">
<table width="70%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td><div align="center">
            <!--SLIDESHOW CODE-->
            <a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image1','','potatos/3.jpg',1)"></a>
            <!--/SLIDESHOW CODE-->
            <a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('attack4','','potatos/wbr.png',1)"><img src="potatos/attack4.gif" alt="Dance!" name="attack4" width="500" height="278" border="0"></a></div></td>
        </tr>
  </table>
<table width="60%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="15">
        <td><div align="center" class="style5">Nugget's Club </div></td>
        <tr>
          <td>
          <?php
?>
          <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    ?>
            <div align="center"><span class="style6">Welcome: <a href="perfil.php?id=<?=$_SESSION['usuario_id']?>"><strong>
            <?=$_SESSION['username']?>
            </strong></a></span><a href="perfil.php?id=<?=$_SESSION['usuario_id']?>"><strong>           </strong></a><br />
          <a href="logout.php"></a>            </div></td>        
        <tr>
          <td></td>
  </table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="25" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">    <?php
        }else {
    ?>
            <a href="registro.php">Signup</a> | <a href="acceso.php">Login</a>
    <?php
        }
    ?> </th>
      </tr>
    </table></th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<?php include_once("header_bottom.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

> The top part is the main page
>   bottom part is the login page

```
       <?php
    session_start();
    include('acceso_db.php');
?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><style type="text/css">
    <!--
    body {
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    -->
    </style></head>
    <body>
    <?php include_once("header_top.php"); ?>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="center">
                      <table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td><div align="center"></div></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="80" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td><div align="center">  <?php
            if(empty($_SESSION['username'])) { // comprobamos que las variables de sesión estén vacías        
        ?>
                <form action="comprobar.php" method="post">
                    READY TO LOGIN? <label>
                    <div align="left">Username</div>
                    </label>
                    <div align="left"><br />
                        <input type="text" name="username" />
                      <br />
                      </div>
                    <label>
                    <div align="left">Password</div>
                    </label>
                    <div align="left"><br />
                        <input type="password" name="usuario_clave" />
                      <br />
                        <a href="recuperar_contrasena.php">Lost Password</a><br />
                        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Ingresar" />
                      </div>
                </form>                    
                <div align="left">
                  <?php
            }else {
        ?>






              </div>
              <?php
?>
            <p align="left">Hello <strong><?=$_SESSION['username']?></strong> , are you already signed up? <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> and log back in. Maybe your wanting to <a href="registro.php">Signup</a>?</p>
            <p>
              <?php
        }
    ?>  
            </p></div></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  </div></td>
              </tr>
            </table>





<?php include_once("header_bottom.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

> I put it back to my own code, because I kind of got confused on where to put it. I put it on the top for both and it showed up although the welcome guest shows up all the way to the top.
>   The code on the bottom is where i want the text to be.

```
              <?php
?>
            <p align="left">Hello <strong><?=$_SESSION['username']?></strong> , are you already signed up? <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> and log back in. Maybe your wanting to <a href="registro.php">Signup</a>?</p>
            <p>
              <?php
        }
    ?>  
            </p></div></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  </div></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Millions of people know exactly what you want so it's unlikely you have looked around at all. Please edit your question to include what you have tried. We are not a free coding service, we will help you with issues within your current code.

Comment: I can really show you the code, because since it didn't work I took it off and put my code the way it was, and took off the page. I just tried looking for it, but couldn't find it. Although I can show you my current code if that helps. I know your not a free coding service, this website is to ask a question you can't find on your own and see if they help you. Of course if they don't want to thats fine, it was worth a try. You have no right to tell someone else to not help someone else who needs help. So please keep it nice, i have no idea how to work with codes but im trying, and i can't easil

Comment: easily look for these kind of stuff because im not sure how to look for what im looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's assume user logs in, and correct credentials are set.

So we set a session with the username (in this case Script47). So something like this.

```
// Blah blah above user logs in...
// $username is the value of the login form. You have now set SESSION "username" to that value
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

There after, when on a "main" page (the page after login) have this.

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo 'Welcome Guest.'; // Your message here.
} else {
    echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['username'];
}
```

***Don't forget to start session when setting session.***

Comment: Answering a bad question invites more bad questions.

Comment: @Zanderwar what do you suggest I do?

Comment: Your answer is accurate, but try not to help people who obviously don't even try.

Comment: @Zanderwar duly noted.

Comment: @auburn he based his assumption on the question you posted, it wasn't exactly very thought through, a simple Google search could get you the results. However did you try my answer?

Comment: @script47 i want to show you how I put it but i don't know how to edit my post, do you have an idea on how to

Comment: @auburn http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @auburn did you try running the code?

Comment: I did I posted it in although where it says the welcome guest it just shows up all the way to the top of the page.

Comment: @auburn what about if you login?

Comment: Okay so I took it off and put it again, so I made sure I didn't put anything wrong. And so the code that says welcome username works now. It shows up when the person has login in. And doesn't when the person logs off. Although your code didn't appear at all. Maybe is because my code was there on top. Hmm not sure im explaining myself very much.